# how to return just selected items from checkboxlist?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to return the items that I have selected in my angular js app. The app shows a few facilities coming from a json file:

```
{"facility": [
    {
        "facilityItem": {
            "value": "Public_telephone",
            "code": "Public_telephone"
        }
    },
    {
        "facilityItem": {
            "value": "Public_toilet",
            "code": "Public_toilet"
        }
    }
]
}
```

In the angular js page I am listing those items:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="facility in items">
          <input type="checkbox"/>
          {{facility.facilityItem.code}} &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Question is how can I create an object say selectedItems which contains all the facilityitems that are checked in this list?

plnkr reference:http://plnkr.co/edit/rfzCBi?p=preview

Comment: is it ok to add property to the existing objects? If so is very simple

Comment: simplest approach  http://plnkr.co/edit/coQY5e?p=preview

Comment: hi I dont want to add a property to the existing model

Answer (score 1):

The input box must be bound to an angular model with ng-model:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="facility in items">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="facility.facilityItem.selected"/>
          {{facility.facilityItem.code}} &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Once you do that, the "selected" property in each `facilityItem` should be defined once selected.

**Alternative way that uses a different model**

Add this to your controller to create a new model:

```
$scope.facilitySelected = [];
```

And then change your html to use the new model; note that $index is view dependent, so the model and view must be in the same order (I discourage aligned arrays).

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="facility in items">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="facilitySelected[$index]"/> 
          {{facility.facilityItem.code}} &nbsp; {{facilitySelected[$index] && "selected" || "" }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: hi,is it possible to return this selection without adding the selected property to the model?

Comment: Added a different solution with a seperate model

Comment: facilitySelected only contains booleans no objects?